# DRF: How to use urls with UUID

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

So, I would like top stop ursing `urlpatterns` and just use `router`. But instead of using ID of an object I'm using UUID instead and I'm using it with urlpatterns and dont't find some way to use it with `routers`.
this is my current model:

```py
class Board(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
```

this is my core app `urls.py`:

```py
...

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'boards', BoardViewSet)
router.register(r'y', yViewSet)
router.register(r'z', zViewSet, basename='z')


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('board-list/<uuid:pk>/', BoardViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='boards'),
]
```

and this is the project `urls.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from core.urls import router as api_router

routes = []
routes.extend(api_router.urls)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include((routes, 'board_microservice'), namespace='v1')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

the application usage is ok, but I have some troubles with test.
i.e:
this works well:

```py
    url = reverse('v1:board-list')

    response = api_client().get(
        url
    )
```

and it isn't working:

```py
board = baker.make(Board)
url = reverse('v1:board-list', kwargs={"pk": board.id})
response = api_client().get(url)
```

I receive

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'board-list' with keyword arguments`

and I think I can replace `urlpatterns` by `router` to solve it and turns it more simple

There is any way to do it with router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shared your view, but it seems you are using a `ModelViewSet` and you seem to be looking for the `retrieve` endpoint rather than `list` (judging from using a `pk`). If so then you want to use `-detail` instead of `-list`:

```
url = reverse('v1:board-detail', kwargs={"pk": board.id})
```

Answer (score 0):

Board_list is not what you want to call... Try board_get instead.

Board list takes no argument. But get does.. To get a particular board.